# Deactivate highlighting of special characters in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, special-characters, highlight

[image: Highlighted special characters]

The more i try to dig in the VSCode settings, i cant seem to find out how do deactivate that, and I'm wondering if someone knows. Thanks in advance

I navigated through the whole settings things of VSCode including the json and found nothing

Comment: search the settings UI for `unicode` there are 7 settings

Answer (score 2):

Go to **settings** and search for **Unicode Highlight** and set it to **false**